# How can I catch or suppress a rejected network request from Jest?

Tags: jestjs, jsdom

I'm working on an HTTP mocking library and am writing a test that asserts my library does *not* intercept a request to a particular URL. I'm using Jest.

Here's the test:

```js
test("it can passthrough individual paths", async () => {
  server.passthrough("/addresses");

  try {
    await fetch("/addresses");
  } catch (e) {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  }
});
```

The test passes, but here's my output:

[image: screen]

I believe this is jsdom writing an error because of the unhandled network request. But in my case, this is expected.

How might I suppress or override this console message? When I ran these tests in the browser in my previous QUnit setup, there was no extra logging printed to the screen once I used `catch` to handle the error. Hoping for something similar here, without me having to monkey patch either `fetch` or `console`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be jsdom's [virtual console](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#virtual-consoles) (which will report all request errors independently of code flow (and script errors when not caught) - like a browser would). You can suppress the output relatively easily:

**jest.config.js**

```
const { VirtualConsole } = require('jsdom');
const virtualConsole = new VirtualConsole();
// default virtualConsole has sendTo(console) defined

module.exports = {
  "testEnvironmentOptions": { virtualConsole }
}
```